# How to remove a (RelativeLayout.ALIGN_START) rule

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app where I have two different views. Both views are actually canvas drawings (drawn programmatically) with a bunch of text views and buttons on top. The positions of these buttons and text views need to be changed depending on the view selection. I created a relative layout with my drawing and the buttons and text views. I use one of the text views as an anchor for the others and programmatically change its position.

Here is a part of the xml:

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvAnchor"
        android:layout_above="@id/btnCtrl"
        android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/lightGrey"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Select1"
        android:background="@drawable/controls_border_not_active"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvAlign"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvAnchor"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tvAnchor"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/lightGrey"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Select2"
        android:background="@drawable/controls_border_not_active"
        android:clickable="true"/>
```

In my main I have the following code to change the position of the text views accordingly:

```
private void PositionControls(){

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lopAnchor = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tvAnchor.getLayoutParams();

    if (isView1Selected){
        lopAnchor.resolveLayoutDirection(relativeLayout.getLayoutDirection());
        lopAnchor.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_START);
        lopAnchor.setMargins(0,0,0,370);
        lopAnchor.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    }else{                      
       lopAnchor.setMargins(0,0,0,300);
       lopAnchor.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
       lopAnchor.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_START,swDoIt.getId());
    }    
    tvAnchor.setLayoutParams(lopAnchor);

}
```

Basically, in View1, the tvAnchor should be centered horizontally and in the other view it should be positioned off center - in the middle of 'center-to-right screen edge'. In order to do that when the second view is selected I remove the CENTER_HORIZONTAL rule and add a rule 'ALIGN_START' with a switch that is already positioned in the desired X coordinate. It works just fine. The problem occurs when View 1 is selected again and I switch from View 2 to View 1. In this situation I remove the ALIGN_START rule and add the CENTER_HORIZONTAL one. The thing is that tvAnchor remains aligned to the switch as if the ALIGN_START rule was not removed. I tried to get the direction of the layout, used requestLayout and other things that could think of, but nothing seems to remove that rule.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that there isn't coming some mystery values enabled??

I had case where is moved clockwidget place in layout

I did add ALIGN_PARENT_END and removed CENTER_IN_PARENT but when i set layout back i could not get clock widget centered.

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mTextClockWidget.getLayoutParams();
    p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, 1);
    p.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    mTextClockWidget.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Then noticed that from somewhere my layout params got ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT enabled and when tried to remove ALIGN_PARENT_END and enable CENTER_IN_PARENT it didn't work. So i had to also add remove for ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT to get it work.

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mTextClockWidget.getLayoutParams();
    p.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
    p.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    p.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 1);
    mTextClockWidget.setLayoutParams(p);
```